# Java Retrieve child nodes with different tag names in the order in which they appear in an xml document

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an xml file which looked something like this...

```
<RootElementTag>
   <ChildElementTag1 attribute1="value1" />
   <ChildElementTag1 attribute1="value2" />
   <ChildElementTag1 attribute1="value4" />
</RootElementTag>
```

I had to retrieve all the "ChildElementTag1" nodes and process them in the order in which they appear in the file. I used `org.w3c.dom.Document.getElementsByTagName("ChildElementTag1");` which returned me a NodeList in the order in which it appears in the xml file.

Now the xml changed a bit and a new Child node with a different tag name "ChildElementTag2" is included.

```
<RootElementTag>
   <ChildElementTag1 attribute1="value1" />
   <ChildElementTag1 attribute1="value2" />
   <ChildElementTag2 attribute2="value3" />
   <ChildElementTag1 attribute1="value4" />
   <ChildElementTag2 attribute2="value5" />
</RootElementTag>
```

Is there a way to get all the 5 Child Element Nodes in the above xml snippet in the order in which they appear.

Note:- I did see `org.w3c.dom.Document.getElementById()` method which would need me to introduce an "id" attribute to each child node and order them based on their "id" attribute value. As of now I am not taking that approach hoping there is an easier way of doing this.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781568/update-data-in-java-class-as-per-change-in-attribute-in-the-xml-file/9783154#9783154

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`getChildNodes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes%28%29) on the `RootTagElement` node.

---

> The javadoc for this method does not mention that the NodeList returned in the order in which it appears in the document.

I suspect you'll find they are in the same order as they appear in the document.  OTOH, you might also look to methods listed just below the one to which I linked.  Specifically `getFirstChild()` & `getNextSibling()` (which you would call on the first child, then repeatedly until `null`).

Comment: Tried it out and it worked as you said. The ordering is maintained. Thanks Andrew !!

Comment: Maybe so, but you made a good point about there being no contract or obligation to be returned in the same order as the XML.  I think you are better off looking to first child & siblings, which (by my reading of the docs & method names) *would* guarantee the original order.