# update data in java class as per change in attribute in the xml file

Tags: java, xml

I want to add an attribute  to the xml defination file

Now i want this change to be reflected in a java class . Can you suggest as to how it can be done . Also i want to add this attribute as a data member in one java class with it;s getter and setters . That i have done . I want to know how to  assign the value from the node of the xml into the java attribute in this class . Please tell me only logic .

Comment: Just for clarification: do you want to change the *source code* or the compiled *class file*? That's not clear to me.

Comment: Andreas i just the logic to assign the value from the node of the xml into the java attribute into the method
public void init(Node node) . Can you help me out in this . Please note that members of the java class are in sync as the attributes in the xml file . So please tell me how to assign the values from the  nodes into the corresponding attributes in the java class .

Comment: Basically there is an xsd file . I want to add one attribute to this xsd file . Now this change should be reflected in a java class dataservices.DataServicesLayout.java adding the new constant like ex:- public static final String SERVICE ID= "serviceId" . Second objective is to add the attribute private String serviceId and it's getter and setter methods in another java class . Then we need to assign the value from the node of the xml file into the java attribute into the method public void init(Node node)

Answer (score 1):

As you already have a schema for your xml files and you want java classes for the data types, consider using [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net). This xml binding API can autogenerate classes from schemas and it provides convenient methods to marshal and unmarschal XML documents. (IAW: "convert an XML into java instances and vice versa).

Comment: i just want the logic to  assign the value from the node of the xml into the java attribute into a method . Other requirements i sorted out . Can you help in this regard .

Comment: There is no simple "logic". If you want to do it automatically - use JAXB or the framework that initially autogenerated the classes and simply rerun the autogeneration. If you want to do it by hand - analysze the schema, then the source files and finally the binding rules/logic, then write field(s) and methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement using this code

your attribute.xml

```
<attributes>
    <attribute-list>
            <attribute>
                <fname>riddhish</fname>
            <lname>chaudhari</lname>
        </attribute>
    </attribute-list>
<attributes>
```

Class File

```
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_LIST = "ATTRIBUTE_LIST";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE = "ATTRIBUTE";
public static final String FNAME = "FNAME";
```

Code for rading attributes from xml file

```
Document document = null;
NodeList nodeList = null;
Node node = null;

nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("----file attributes.xml---").item(0).getChildNodes();
HashMap <String,Object> localParameterMap  = new HashMap<String,Object>();

for(int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++){
    node = nodeList.item(i);
    if(node.getNodeName().equals("attribute-list")){
        Collection objCollection = readAttributeList(node);
        localParameterMap.put(ATTRIBUTE_LIST, objCollection);
    }
}
```

function() readAttributeList

```
private Collection readAttributeList(Node node){
    Collection<Object> objCollection = new ArrayList<Object>();
    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();   

    for(int i=0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++){
        Node subNode = nodeList.item(i);

        if(subNode.getNodeName().equals("attribute")){
            NodeList attributeList = subNode.getChildNodes();
            HashMap <String,Object> attributeMap  = new HashMap<String,Object>();

                for(int j=0; j<attributeList.getLength(); j++){
                    Node attributeNode = attributeList.item(j);

                    if(attributeNode.getNodeName().equals("fname")){
                        attributeMap.put(FNAME, attributeNode.getTextContent().trim());
                    }   
                }
        }
        objCollection.add(attributeMap);
    }
    return objCollection;
}
```

for reading attribute values in variable

```
String strfname = null;

if(map.get(CLASS_NAME.FNAME) != null) {
    strfname = (String)map.get(CLASS_NAME.FNAME);
}
```